# suggesting words on when character is typed in search box

Tags: jquery, html, css

Like in google.com search box, when I type a character, it starts suggesting words and queries.

I need to have similar functionality on my webpage.

Can you please point me to right direction. Any tip/docs will be helpful

I have no idea where to start other than Stackoverflow.

Comment: did try to google it? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: jquery ui autocomplete, typeahead, I'm sure there are others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind adding jQuery Ui dependency you could use [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Here you have a very simple example taken from documentation.

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>
```